# IOS sqlite update query issues

Tags: sql, ios, uitableview

I am very new to IOS programming so I am not quite sure how this issue can be best solved.

I have a database of events that are being displayed on a tableview, when you select one of those items, it shows details along with the option to save it as a "favorite" which just updates a column in the db and sets it to 1.

I have a second table view that looks for all instances that have their "favorite" set to 1.

The problem I have run into is that I have only figured out how to get the "updateItem" database query to function off of the path of the item that you selected.  Since each tableview shows the same item on different paths, the "updateItem" query is updating the incorrect item in the database when you are using the "favorites" table view.

I understand that in the UpdateItemAtID method, it is using the aryDatabase, and the favorites query uses the aryDatabaseFav.  I had to create the second array the get around the favorites tableview, maybe there is a better way to have everything I want with just the original aryDatabase array rather than having 2 different arrays.

Here is the code I have for the two select statements as well as the update query, is there a better way that I can get around needing the path of the item?

```c
-(void)readItems {

if (!database) return; // earlier problems
if (!selStmt)
{
    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Events;";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        selStmt = nil;
    }
}
if (!selStmt)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Can't build SQL to read items [%s]", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

// loop reading items from list
[aryDatabase removeAllObjects]; // clear list for rebuild
int ret;
while ((ret=sqlite3_step(selStmt))==SQLITE_ROW) 
{ // get the fields from the record set and assign to item
    //bindings omitted
    [aryDatabase addObject:se]; // add to list
    [se release]; // free item
}
sqlite3_reset(selStmt); // reset (unbind) statement
selStmt = nil;}

-(void)readFavItems {
if (!database) return; // earlier problems
if (!selStmt)
{
    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE mySchedule = 1;";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        selStmt = nil;
    }
}
if (!selStmt)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Can't build SQL to read items [%s]", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

// loop reading items from list
[aryDatabaseFav removeAllObjects]; // clear list for rebuild
int ret;
while ((ret=sqlite3_step(selStmt))==SQLITE_ROW) 
{ // get the fields from the record set and assign to item
    //bindings omitted
    [aryDatabaseFav addObject:se]; // add to list
    [se release]; // free item
}
sqlite3_reset(selStmt); // reset (unbind) statement
selStmt = nil;}

-(void)updateItemAtID:(NSIndexPath *)path {
singleEvent *i = (singleEvent *)[aryDatabase objectAtIndex:path.row];
int ret;

const char *sql = "UPDATE events SET mySchedule = ? WHERE _id = ?;";

if (!updStmt)
{ // build update statement
    if ((ret=sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updStmt, NULL))!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error building statement to update items [%s]", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
// bind values to statement
NSInteger m = i.intId;
sqlite3_bind_int(updStmt, 1, m);
NSInteger p = i.intPk;
sqlite3_bind_int(updStmt, 2, p);

if ((ret=sqlite3_step(updStmt)) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating values [%s]", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
    sqlite3_reset(updStmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the code and getting a result=0 on sqlite3_bind_text. Does mean it was updated with no error or no record was updated at all? Not sure what else to do at this point...

```
   BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bh.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    NSLog(writableDBPath);

    if(success)
    {
        const char *dbPath= [writableDBPath UTF8String];

        //[G msgBox:writableDBPath title:@""];

        //const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        sqlite3 *contactDB = NULL;

        if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSString *updateSQL = @"UPDATE account SET name = ? ";
            const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];


            int e = sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, update_stmt, -1, &statement, nil);
            if(e != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"Problem with updateEntryWithUniqueID");
                NSLog(@"Error Code: %d, message '%s'", e, sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

                return;
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Updated");
                [G setNickname:thisNickname];
            }

            int result=sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [thisNickname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            NSLog(@"bind result= %i", result);


            if(sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                NSLog(@"Problems updating");
            }

            /* Finished */ 
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"Can not open DB.");
        }

    }else{
        NSLog(@"path not exsist");        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Base of my understanding, it seems like the way the NSArray is structured when they load the data could be different since you are using NSIndexPath.

I do recommend the following approach, using a Singleton Object.

Singleton Object works like a container that is shared among a fews view controller(s) or classes.

Back to your issue, you can store the object (singleEvent) in the Singleton for the other uitableview to pick it up.

This is assuming that your singleEvent object have the key fields such as Id.

Hope this helps.