# inserted data is not shown in main database in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm learning sqlite in iphone in which I hava a query that when adding the sqlite  file in to resources folder and running the application it works fine but data is not shown when I'm opening that sqlite file in sql manager. Plz give me a solution for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, nobody is there to code a script for you. When you face a problem, first do some research (use google, search this site itself, etc.) Then you'll definitely come to a general idea of what your problem might be. Now apply your research in your work. See if it works or not. If there is no luck, do not hesitate to ask your question here. Programmers from all around the world will be more than happy to guide you further. (You will be able to show them what you have done so far by then) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...adding the sqlite file in to ***resources*** folder..."

later

> "...data is not shown when I'm opening that sqlite file in sql manager..."

Because you can't write/modify files in the app bundle (for quite obvious security considerations).

If you want to modify a file programmatically, you have to copy it to the Library or Documents directory.

But really, you ***should have googled.*** There are several questions and answers about the very same problem, for example:

[SQLite3 update not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514187/sqlite3-update-not-working)

[IOS sqlite update query issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673535/ios-sqlite-update-query-issues)

[sqlite3 update not working in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439751/sqlite3-update-not-working-in-ios)

[sqlite database not updating modified data in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636009/sqlite-database-not-updating-modified-data-in-iphone-sdk)

(Want more?)